# la configuración que uso en mi router no permite que pueda usar no-ip

Tags: ip

Al momento de querer configurar DDNS en mi router sagemcom, ingreso el servicio DDNS "no-ip" y mi usuario y contraseña, también mi hostname, pero lo raro es que me aparece un ip 10.227.56.x.
Y ese ip es diferente al ip  que me aparece en los buscadores de google cualesmiip.com el cual es : 179.7.226.26.

y el aplicativo de no-ip detecta automaticamente el ip de "cualesmiip.com" y al final nunca detecta el hostname que he creado en no-ip.

Comment: Comprueba que tu proveedor no esté usando un proxy

Answer (score 0):

Todo el segmento `10/8` (es decir, desde `10.0.0.0` hasta `10.255.255.255`) es para redes privadas... si tu equipo tiene una IP de ese segmento y estás navegando, quiere decir que hay un NAT en el camino que le pone una IP pública y esa es la que se vería en cualquier sitio web por ahí.... que en tu caso sería la `179.7.226.26`.